Merging overlapping points and adjusting their size based on sample count in QGIS
I have a data set like the following in .csv:



sample
latitude
longitude




A
37.18
-115.85


B
37.18
-115.85


C
37.18
-115.85


D
39.44
-117.66


E
39.36
-117.72


F
39.6
-117.94


G
38.12
-111.5


H
37.95
-114.36



Some locations have multiple samples (e.g., samples A, B, and C are from the same location). When I load this dataset as a point layer in QGIS, the overlapping points cause overplotting.
I would like to:

Merge points that share the same latitude and longitude into a single point.
Adjust the size of the resulting points so that they are proportional to the number of samples at each location.

What is the best way to achieve this in QGIS?

Look at the Create Points Layer from Table tool to create points from your table.  It is a temporary layer, you can export it to a permanent layer if you like.  Then look at the dissolve tools such as GDAL Dissolve tool which has a count dissolve features option.  Then look at the symbology options such as categories based on the count field.

You can achieve this using a Virtual layer that groups by X and Y, creates the point and counts the number of original rows per group.
Remember that a virtual layer is, well, virtual, so it is recomputed each time you touch the map. You may want to export the resulting layer to a persistent storage.
Add the csv table to QGIS (just the table, don't create points).
Go to the menu Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer... and enter the query. Note that I have aggregated the sample names together.
select make_point(longitude,latitude) as geometry, count(*) as count,
 latitude, longitude, 
 group_concat(sample,',') as samples
from sample
group by longitude,latitude


Then you can either use a categorized style based on the size, or keep a simple style and set a data-defined override on the size. Click the epsilon icon beside the size, then edit and enter count as the expression.


If you want to avoid the constant recomputing of virtual layer or skip the export part you may use the "Execute SQL" processing tool with the same query

Another solution can be produced with QGIS tools:

Drag & drop the CSV into QGIS, change the data source encoding if needed

Make use of the "Create points layer from table"

Apply the "Aggregate" with the following parameters:

Group by expression: geom_to_wkt( $geometry )
for "sample" field - concatenate function
for "latitude" field - first_value function
for "longitude" field - first_value function



